# Applying cell-wise function in a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe and would like to replace each cell value based the formula
`new_val = current_val/#days` in the month. Let's say the dataframe looks like:

```
     2012    2013    2014
Jan   10     12       11
Feb   8       9       10
Mar   11      11      13
```

Then, if number of days in Jan 2012 is 31, then the new cell value corresponding to Jan 2012 will be 10/31. Similarly, the value of March 2014 would be 13/31 and so on.

I was thinking of applying the `applymap` function, but I am struggling with the syntax:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x/(monthrange(A,B)[1]))
```

where A = year, and B = month. I was wondering if anyone can help me with proper indexes for A and B.

The output will be:

```
       2012     2013    2014
Jan   0.3226   0.3870  0.3548
Feb   0.2758   0.3214  0.3571
Mar   0.3548   0.3548  0.4193
```

Comment: can you give an output format?

Comment: The output will be a dataframe with replaced cell values - I am editing my question to show the output

Comment: Is it possible that there will be 2 months with the same number in the same column?

Comment: Yes, it's quite possible if the initial cell values are the same and the #days in those two months are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `df.applymap(func)`, the function `func` only gets passed the DataFrame
values. It does not get passed the corresponding index and column labels. So I
don't see a way you could use `df.applymap` here.

Instead, you could unstack `df`, and use its index, `df.stack().index`, and `pd.to_datetime` to parse the index and column labels into dates:

```
result = df.stack()
# Jan  2012    10
#      2013    12
#      2014    11
# Feb  2012     8
#      2013     9
#      2014    10
# Mar  2012    11
#      2013    11
#      2014    13
# dtype: int64

dates = pd.to_datetime([' '.join(item) for item in result.index])
# DatetimeIndex(['2012-01-01', '2013-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2012-02-01',
#                '2013-02-01', '2014-02-01', '2012-03-01', '2013-03-01',
#                '2014-03-01'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None, tz=None)
```

and then use the `DatetimeIndex.days_in_month` property to find out the number
of days in each month:

```
days = dates.days_in_month
# array([31, 31, 31, 29, 28, 28, 31, 31, 31], dtype=int32)
```

Now divide `result` by the number of days in each month:

```
In [140]: result/days
Out[140]: 
Jan  2012    0.322581
     2013    0.387097
     2014    0.354839
Feb  2012    0.275862
     2013    0.321429
     2014    0.357143
Mar  2012    0.354839
     2013    0.354839
     2014    0.419355
dtype: float64
```

and unstack to obtain the desired result:

```
(df.stack()/days).unstack()
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'2012': [10, 8, 11], '2013': [12, 9, 11], '2014': [11, 10, 13]},
                  index='Jan Feb Mar'.split())

result = df.stack()
dates = pd.to_datetime([' '.join(item) for item in result.index])
days = dates.days_in_month
result = (result / days).unstack()
print(result)
```

yields

```
         2012      2013      2014
Jan  0.322581  0.387097  0.354839
Feb  0.275862  0.321429  0.357143
Mar  0.354839  0.354839  0.419355
```

---

For older versions of Pandas (prior to v.0.16), you could use

```
days = (dates + pd.DateOffset(months=1, days=-1)).day
```

instead of

```
days = dates.days_in_month
```

to find the number of days in each month.

Comment: FYI there is a Series.dt.days_in_month added in 0.16 iirc (but not documented) in the formal docs

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. There are so many good things packed into each new version of Pandas, it is hard to keep up :)

Answer (score 2):

Both ways I will be showing will need this dictionary and import:

```
names_to_months = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, .... }
import calendar
```

1. This way **might be very slow** depending on the size of your dataframe but will always return the correct result:

   ```
   for index in df.index:
       for column in df.columns:
           df[column] = df[column].astype(float)
           df.at[index, column] = round(df.ix[index, column] / calendar.monthrange(int(column), names_to_months[index])[1], 4)
   ```

   The problem with the `apply`/`map`/`applymap` functions is that they don't
   provide an easy way to track and access **both** the column name and the index of the
   current cell/row they operate on.
2. Here is a faster code using `apply`, but **it will provide wrong result** in case there are 2 or more months in the same column with the same value, because `np.where` returns an `np.array` of the indexes that it found the value of `x` in, but there's no way to store it and use the next index the next time we encounter the same `x` value:

   ```
    for col in list(df.columns):
         df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x / calendar.monthrange(int(col), names_to_months[df.index[np.where(df[col] == x)[0][0]]])[1])
   ```